# Can I open the "Network Connections" form in Windows 10 directly from the Start Menu?

Tags: windows-10

I routinely need to access the "Network Connections" form in Windows.  In Windows 7 I could access this form from the Start Menu by typing "View Network Connections", bypassing the unhelpful "Network and Sharing Center" form.

In Windows 10, the best option I have found is pressing Win + X, then W, then clicking "Change adapter options".

Can anyone tell me how to go directly to this form?

Comment: Why can't you do Start > "View Network Connections" in Windows 10? That works for me.

Comment: @freginold - that option is not available.  If I type "View Network connections", it wants to do a web search on the term.

Comment: Over time it seems that settings appear and disappear from my Start Menu in Windows 10.  Currently, typing "View Network Connections" in the Start Menu only offers me an option to search the web :-(

Comment: Hmm, maybe an indexing issue, or not searching the Control Panel? On my Windows 10 PC that option shows up at the top of the list.

Comment: I assume it is an indexing issue.  Though I confess to occasionally thinking that Microsoft is steering me away from Control Panel toward Settings, when a setting that was lost reappears I'm left thinking its an indexing issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open "Network Connections" as described in your question.
Drag the icon to the left of the address bar (where "Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections" is written) and drop it to the Desktop.

Or create shortcut with command line:

```
explorer.exe shell:::{992CFFA0-F557-101A-88EC-00DD010CCC48}
```

Comment: Thank you Akina!  I added a shortcut to the Start Menu and now have exactly the behavior I was looking for.

Comment: or simply just `ncpa.cpl` in run. I remember it like Network Connections PAnel

Answer (score 6):

Open Start Menu > Run (or press Win-key + R):

```
ncpa.cpl
```

You can also add a shortcut to your desktop. Right-click anywhere > New > Shortcut and type:

```
ncpa.cpl
```